# Converting SQl statement to Linq in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have tried converting a particular SQL Statement to Linq. This SQL statement was used in a legacy application but I want to convert same to Linq but having issues with it. Belos is the SQL Statement.

```
"SELECT Item_Id, Item_Name, Price, SUM(qty) As Qty, SUM(qty * salesPrice) AS Amount, Customer_Name FROM OrderDetails WHERE Order_date BETWEEN @startdate And @enddate GROUP BY product_Id,Product_Name, price, Customer_Name ORDER BY Product_Name";
```

Below is the Linq I have been able to come up with.

```
List<OrderDetail> orderDetails = (from l in db.OrderDetails
                                          where (l.Order_ID.Contains(search) || search == null)
                                          && (l.Order_Date >= startingdate.Date && l.Order_Date < Nenddate.Date)
                                          let Amount = ((double)l.Qty) * ((double)l.salesPrice)
                                          select new details
                                          {
                                              Item_ID = l.Item_ID
                                              Item_Name = l.Item_Name
                                              
                                              Qty = l.Qty,
                                              salesPrice = l.salesPrice,
                                              Amount = Amount,
                                              
                                          };
                                        select l).ToList();
```

I will like also group the outcome by Item_Name and Item_ID.
Anyone point me to how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Your original Sql query can be rewritten as

```
var query =
  from l in db.OrderDetails
  where (l.Order_ID.Contains(search) || search == null)
       && (l.Order_Date > = startingdate.Date && l.Order_Date < Nenddate.Date)
  group l by new 
  {
      l.product_Id, l.Product_Name, l.price, l.Customer_Name
  } into g
  select new 
  {
      g.Key,
      Amount = g.Sum( p => (double)p.Qty * (double)p.salesPrice )     
  };
```

The `query` can be used for a further grouping as you wish.

Comment: Amazing. Let me try it out..